# Configure Apache server to use specific OpenSSL Engine

Tags: apache, openssl, mod-ssl, openssl-engine

I have a working OpenSSL RSA engine (i.e. a `.so` file) and an Apache server configured in SSL mode.
How can I make Apache use RSA implementation from my RSA engine? In other words: Where do I put the engine (`.so` file), how do I modify the `openssl.cnf` file and how do I build the Apache?

Comment: [Custom OpenSSL engine when running within Apache via mod_ssl](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180343) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange and [Integrating Apache with PKCS#11 device via engine_pkcs11 and OpenSSL](http://serverfault.com/q/711580) on Server Fault.

Comment: Hi jww, I have already read the first link you provided, but I do not know how to modify the `openssl.cnf` file. Do you think [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/config.html) would be a good start?

Comment: @jww I modified the `openssl.cnf` file and I added my engine as stated in the link that I had provided in the previous comment. [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcryptodevice) says "To discover which engine names are supported, run the command "openssl engine" ", but my engine id doesn't appear in the list. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps that worked for me:

1.Install OpenSSL from sources, specifying `-DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF` when running `./config`
1.1.Create/build your OpenSSL engine and add it to your `openssl.cnf` file
2.Install httpd from sources, using these commands:

```
CFLAGS='-DSSL_EXPERIMENTAL_ENGINE -DSSL_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF' ./configure --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre --enable-so      
make       
make install
```

2.1.Edit `httpd-ssl.conf` by adding `SSLCryptoDevice engine_id` and make sure that when execute `$ openssl engine`, the `engine_id` specifier appears on the list. Also, you have to create self-signed cerificate and private key, modify the `httpd.conf` file, but this is not the subject of this question. Search: how to configure HTTPS on Apache.
3.`$ httpd -k restart` and that is all.

**EDIT**
The place of `.so` file (Openssl ENGINE) must be specified in `openssl.cnf`.

Answer (score 2):

For a start I don't fully understand your question. I presume you mean you've a version of OpenSSL installed on your system that Apache is using and you want to use a different (presumably later version) that you've also downloaded and installed?

It really depends which platform (Windows or Linux), how you installed Apache (pre-installed on system, through a package manager like yum or apt-get, or manually installed from source).

Prebuilt packages like those in Windows installs and package managers tend to use the system default SSL library and aren't the easiest to change (though I'm not familiar enough with them all to be honest).

So the easiest way to do this is to install Apache from source code rather than from a prebuilt package.

You normally need to set this at compile time , after downloading the source, using the --with-ssl option to configure before using make to build your code:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --enable-ssl --enable-so
```

If you've not installed from source before then this can be a bit intimidating. I've given detailed instructions on a blog post here on HTTP2 on how to download and install the latest OpenSSL and Apache from source on linux: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/ but there may be better options on your specific platform.

Comment: I don't think I understand very well. So when I try to install Apache I should use what you stated in the above answer?

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: I don't want to use a different OpenSSL version. I just want to integrate an [OpenSSL engine](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/engine.html) in order to use a different implementation of the RSA algorithm

Comment: In Linux, the OpenSSL engine is a `.so` file and it can be used, for example, like this: `$ openssl speed rsa -engine pwd/my_engine.so`. Basically I need to know how to integrate this `.so` file with the Apache in order to use my own RSA implementation. I understand that I need to build the Apache from its source files, but I do not know what to do next.

Comment: I would say follow jww's link to create a customer build using a conf file then build Apache with that custom build as per my answer.

Comment: So, I have to modify the `openssl.cnf` file in order to mention the RSA engine and then I have to build the Apache with the options provided by you. The problem is I don't really know how to modify the `openssl.cnf` file and secondly I do not have a `/usr/local/ssl` path, but insted I have `/etc/ssl` and `usr/lib/ssl`. Which should I use?

Comment: I think I figure it out how to edit the OpenSSL configuration file. [This link helped me](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/config.html). One more question: Do I need to recompile the Apache every time I change the `openssl.cnf` file?

Comment: Not sure to be honest but would guess so. Best thing would be to try it and see!